# Managing Linux server from PowerShell using built-in credentials

Tags: ssh, powershell

I am the admin of a small Linux cluster running Ubuntu Server 14.04 and my workstation is Windows 10 Technical Preview (yes, a bold move to use it in production). There is an excellent free scriptable native SSH client for Windows, Posh-SSH using SSH.NET library. Posh-SSH is able to consume PSCredential objects for logging into remote machines. Providing a Linux username and the Kerberos password associated works like a charm.

I intend on automating login by storing this credential using the built-in credential manager of Windows, which seemingly must be using PSCredential types. (Control Panel > Users > Manage Credentials > Windows Credentials > Add a generic credential)

My problem is that all examples issue Get-Credential on the command line and store it in a variable. How can I use the credentials of my user from PS? Are there other convenient ways to provide such PSCredential objects without having to type out usernames and passwords all the time?

Comment: Side note: Are you aware that MS states that it *may* record every user interaction with Win 10 TP? That includes *all* keystrokes, and thus your passwords etc. This product can't be used at all in a production environment.

Comment: I am aware. I am also aware that MS does scan through OneDrive and persecute me if I store child pornography and what not, although EULA states that they don't take responsibility for whatever I store there. At the end of the day, many things boil down to trust, and I don't feel myself important enough for MS to come after my data.

Comment: I'm not going to kill your question, but I am going to strongly suggest you use the right tool for the job. It's generally much easier to manage Linux computers _with_ a Linux computer.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem managing my cluster with the Cygwin port of OpenSSH shipping with practically every Git client on Windows. Does exactly what it's supposed to. OpenSSH restructuring for use as a library will definitely spawn at least one native ssh.exe. I was merely looking for a native solution, and personally I find the script language of PowerShell more powerful and friendly, than bash for eg.

Comment: @Meteorhead This might or might not be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password/6240319#6240319